# Is there a way to dynamically add multiple serveralias to point to the same directory without restarting apache each time?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am using a Ruby on Rails application and currently have it configured to run using Apache and a VirtualHost. However, the virtualhost configuration at the moment is only configured to support my domain. I am looking for a way to be able to dynamically add a `ServerAlias` so that my application can respond to multiple custom domains. I understand that I can just simply add `ServerAlias` to my `VirtualHost` configuration, but this requires me to have reload Apache configuration, which negatively affects the site as there is a 5-10 second pause, if not longer sometimes.

Can I just simply maintain a list of domains in a text file and have Apache point all of those to the same directory as the original virtualhost?

Comment: How many virtual hosts do you have? Can you just make that the default vhost?

Answer (score 0):

Having just the domain names in a file will not work. But you can have such a file, prepend `ServerAlias` to each entry and include that file from the other configuration file.

Independent of that: Reloading should not take that much time. I suggest you examine that problem.

If for whatever reasons your Apache cannot reload quickly then it may be a good idea to put something in front of that Apache what can: HAproxy or nginx. Then you have one static configuration in Apache for those identical domains (running on a separate port) and the proxy decides to which Apache config (port) a request is sent.

Comment: Thanks. The reload command is pretty quick, but the website itself takes about a good 20 seconds to actually refresh. Might need to dig into what could be causing it -- my assumption is something to do with assets and precompiling, but I could be wrong.

With regards to being able to create a simple text file that has ServerAlias <domainName> and include the original file, any additional information on that by chance?

Comment: @LewlSauce Includes are really trivial: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#include But the list file would not include the config file but the other way round. You replace the `ServerAlias` line(s) with the `Include` statement.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks a lot! Going to give this a shot now!